# composer-playground EACCES error when lauching

Tags: hyperledger-composer

When I'm trying to start composer-playground from ubuntu I got the error:

> $ composer-playground info: [Hyperledger-Composer] :LoadModule
>   :loadModule()              Loading composer-wallet-filesystem from
>   /home/rui.oliveira/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/composer-wallet-filesystem
>   info: [Hyperledger-Composer] :PlaygroundAPI            :createServer()
>   Playground API started on port 8080 events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/...log'

When I go to the log file the only entry I've got is:

> 2018-09-21T20:38:52.508Z ERROR   :HLFConnectionManager
>   :fabric-client()           [ChannelEventHub.js]: _connect - timed out
>   after:300000 {}$

My current log level is: `composer[debug]:*`

I'm using REST Server with oauth and multi-user and I can do GET or POST with success (HTTP200) but when I do a POST transaction nothing is set to the peers.

Can someone help trying to debug this?
EACCES is permission denied but not sure what is really being denied here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be because you are running playground and the rest server at the same time both with debug enabled so they might be trying to write to the same log file (unless you have configured each to write to different log files). Info on how to do that can be found at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/problems/diagnostics

Comment: As for your post problem, I am guessing you are running composer 0.20 and fabric 1.2 ? If so where did you get the fabric from ? was it fabric-dev-servers from composer-tools or from fabric-samples for example ? Be useful to know as there appears to be a problem with fabric 1.2 that might be a bug or config issue. Fabric 1.1 and composer 0.19 can be used instead for now.

Comment: @david_k, i have this configuration running for a week now, without problems: composer 0.20, fabric 1.2, rest-server started from docker. I got the fabric from fabric-dev-servers.
Rest-server is also writting in /.composer/logs?
I will stop docker rest and try to start composer-playground to check if it is that...

Comment: I was able to run composer-playground with success (folder permission that was revoked). However, from composer-playground I can submit transactions with success, but are not being setted on peers. Here is what I got from the logs:
INFO    :ConnectionProfileManager :getConnectionManagerByTyp Looking up a connection manager for type {"0":"hlfv1"}$
WARN    :HLFConnection            :_checkCCListener()        could not find any connected event hubs out of 1 defined hubs to listen on for chaincode events {}$

Comment: There have been lots of reports about the same symptoms you are experiencing on composer 0.20 and fabric 1.2. It's definitely a problem with fabric 1.2, not composer. Just not sure whether its a fabric bug or an issue with fabric configuration yet.

Comment: I have been better analyzing the reason for the EACCES error, and an answer can be written:  "playground and the rest server were running at the same time both with debug enabled so they might be trying to write to the same log file". Thanks to @david_k.

However I still have the second problem "transactions not being committed to peers" (which is not related. new question?)

Comment: In my previous comment I said that you are experiencing similar problems to others in this regard (transactions not committing). This is a problem with the fabric itself, either a bug or configuration issue, not sure which at this time.

Comment: If it's a configuration issue then that could be just due to the fabric-dev-server package. You could try a different fabric available from fabric-samples (such as BYFN) or you can use composer 0.19 and fabric 1.1

Comment: There is a bug in hyperledger fabric 1.2 that matches your problem so no pretty certain that the failure to commit transactions is this bug in fabric 1.2. There is a fix coming in 1.2.1 which hopefully will fix it but for now I recommend you move to hyperledger fabric 1.1 and composer 0.19 for now.

Comment: Thanks @david_k. I have downgrade to those specific versions (fabric1.1 & composer0.19) and everythings looks pretty again).